# Resolution-time arguments of same type in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, constructor-injection

When I try to pass two parameters that are of the same type like so:

```
public IPercentage CreatePercentage(int part, int total)
{
    return _container.Resolve<T>(new Arguments(part, total));
}
```

To a constructor like so:

```
public Percentage(int part, int total)
{
   // ...
}
```

Then I get a **System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.**

How can I pass arguments of same type?

- The key thing is I would like to avoid using literal string names of the parameters to identify which arguments goes where
- And instead use the order of the arguments
- and just the fact that it is the only constructor that fits, although I'm guessing the dictionary implementation of Windsor does not allow that.

Comment: Here are two ways to do it: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/02/PrimitiveDependencies

Comment: See also http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/07/AppSettingsconventionforCastleWindsor

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks but which two? I had a quick glance and I'm not sure how to apply it to the current situation given I am talking about arguments provided at resolution-time from code to an injected factory (with the CreatePercentage method) and not arguments provided at composition root; And i mean which two given the need to not use hard-coded string names as that does not work with obfuscation :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. Given your constraints (no string literals), I'm not sure it's possible: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Passing-Arguments.ashx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely doable, correct call [according to documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Arguments.ashx) is:

```
_container.Resolve<IPercentage>(new Arguments(new { part, total }));
```

But the preferred way is to use the [TypedFactoryFacility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx#Resolving_with_arguments_1). You should never call container from your code except the entry point and/or composition root.

Comment: Thanks, it does work! While `new Arguments(part, total)` does not as it is using another overload, which is dictionary-based I believe

Comment: After testing it with obfuscation, turns out this approach does not work - it still relies on the parameter variable names, which get changed on obfuscation ...