# Mixed resolution-time arguments in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, constructor-injection

I have a constructor like this that I would like to pass arguments to from a factory:

```
public Event(IRegisteredType registeredEarly, IPassNow passNowByInterface,
                               DateTimeOffset local, DateTimeOffset world)
{
    // ...
}
```

I tried this approach, but it did not work, because both local and world values where the same, one overwrote the other:

```
public Event CreateEvent(IPassNow passNow, DateTimeOffset local, DateTimeOffset world)
{
    var args = new Arguments { { typeof(IPassNow), passNow } };
    args.InsertTypedCollection(new object[] { local, world });
    return _container.Resolve<Event>(args);
}
```

- registeredEarly should be resolved automatically, it is registered at composition root, and that works
- passNowByInterface should be passed at resolution-time, but because it is an interface I need to specify the interface type, because otherwise Castle Windsor will try to use the concrete type of the argument, again that works - see [Failure to pass generic arguments with Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549577/failure-to-pass-generic-arguments-with-castle-windsor)
- local and world need to be passed at resolution-time as well, but note they are both the same concrete type and I cannot rely on variable names - see [Resolution-time arguments of same type in Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176965/resolution-time-arguments-of-same-type-in-castle-windsor)
- I cannot get the last to work with the rest?

Answer (score 2):

`Resolve` method has several overloads. `Arguments` type is simply `IDictionary` therefore keys cannot be the same.

If you try to create an instance of `Arguments` using its constructor you'll get a 'System.ArgumentException' (An item with the same key has already been added.)

```
var args = new Arguments(new object[] {passNow, local, world});
```

If you debug your code you'll see that there are two items in the dictionary only.

```
var args = new Arguments {{typeof (IPassNow), passNow}};
args.InsertTypedCollection(new object[] {local, world});
```

In order to make it work arguments can be passed as anonimus type.

```
container.Resolve<Event>(new {passNow = passNow, local = local, world = world});
```

There is a test that proves it

```
[Fact]
public void ArgumentsAsAnonimusType()
{
    // Arrange.
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<Event>().ImplementedBy<Event>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IRegisteredType>().ImplementedBy<RegisteredType>());
    var passNow = new PassNow();
    var local = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    var world = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    local.Should().NotBe(world);

    // Act.
    var result = container.Resolve<Event>(new { passNow = passNow, local = local, world = world });

    // Assert.
    result.Should().BeOfType<Event>();
    result.RegisteredType.Should().Be(container.Resolve<IRegisteredType>());
    result.PassNow.Should().Be(passNow);
    result.Local.Should().Be(local);
    result.World.Should().Be(world);
}
```

Comment: this will not work unfortunately as I am passing in the concrete type PassNow whereas the constructor is expecting the interface IPassNow, which needs to therefore be explicitly specified i.e. see the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549577/failure-to-pass-generic-arguments-with-castle-windsor

Comment: sorry, your example does work, because you are specifying literal variable names, but I forgot to mention that I cannot rely on literal variable names because that does not work with obfuscation :( so i cannot do new {passNow = passNow etc because after obfuscation the constructor parameter will not be called passNow any more..

Answer (score 1):

How does your factory looks like ? 
Did you try TypedFactoryFacility ?

For example, in my project I have a consturctor like this:

```
public SomeConcrete(ILog log, IDataBase dataBase, int param1, int param2, int param3, bool somebool)
```

and my factory is:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    SomeConcrete GetSomeConcrete(int param1, int param2, int param3, bool somebool);
}
```

and the resolving by variable names works fine.

If you don't wont to use typed factory, you can try:

```
container.Resolve<ISomeConcrete>(new {param1 = 1, param2 = 2, param3 = 3, somebool = false});
```

More info here [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Resolving_with_arguments_1)

And maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784253/castle-windsor-passing-constructor-parameters) will be usefull too.

Comment: Your example is working because you do not have any interface parameters at resolution-time i.e. you do not have the equivalent of IPassNow or GetSomeConcrete(ILog log, int param1, int param2 ..) - again, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549577/failure-to-pass-generic-arguments-with-castle-windsor

Comment: I see your point now. What I did to handle this is to resolve my reference prior my concrete resolution. Lets say I want to get ILog during the resolution, So it looks like: ILog log = logFactory.GetLog(); Concrete concrete = concreteFactory.GetConcrete(log, param1, param2, param3, somebool);  Hope it helps

Comment: this wont work, try it, because SomeConcrete(ILog log ...) is expecting ILog when you are passing in GetConcrete(log, ..) (which Castle Windsor sees as Log (and not as ILog)

Comment: If you don't register ILog anywhere else, it should work. works for me. Sorry I couldnt help.

Comment: sorry, your example does work, because you are specifying literal variable names, but I forgot to mention that I cannot rely on literal variable names because that does not work with obfuscation :( so i cannot do new {param1 = 1 etc because after obfuscation the constructor parameter will not be called param1 any more..

Comment: In that case, the only thing that I can think about is to create class named EventDate (or something) that will include 2 properties, local and world and pass it to the constructor. that way your constructor will have only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I found a solution:

```
public Event CreateEvent(IPassNow passNow, DateTimeOffset local, DateTimeOffset world)
{
    var args = new Arguments(new { local, world });
    args.Insert(typeof(IPassNow), passNow);
    return _container.Resolve<Event>(args);
}
```

But this does not work with obfuscation either, turns out that new Arguments(new { local, world }); uses parameter literal name as well rather than matching by order or something .. so this is not really an answer ..